# Opening fancybox inline content from a dynamically added link in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have two empty `<div>` like :

```
<div id="fancyboxdiv" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="linkdiv"></div>
```

If I insert a link to one of them (`#linkdiv`) with jQuery and insert the content to the other (`#fancyboxdiv`) when fancybox opens with this script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //loading the opening link to a div with jquery
            $('#linkdiv').html('<a id="fbLink" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fbox">see fancybox</a>');
            //opening the fancybox
            $('#fbLink').fancybox({
                'afterLoad': function() {
                    $('#fancyboxdiv').html('<h1>Fancybox</h1>');
                },
                'afterClose': function() {
                    $('#fancyboxdiv').empty();
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

fancybox fires when I click on the dynamically added link (`#fbLink`) in all browsers but IE8 and lower versions.

If hard-code the link inside `<div id="linkdiv">` like :

```
<div id="linkdiv"><a id="fbLink" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fbox">see fancybox</a></div>
```

and comment out this line of code :

```
//$('#linkdiv').html('<a id="fbLink" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fbox">see fancybox</a>');
```

then fancybox works fine in all browsers including IE8-.

What do I have to do to make my script work in IE8 and lower versions? I need to add the link that fires fancybox at a later time.

Comment: Very good question! I guess the people that down-voted it and voted to close it has no patience with people that don't speak perfect English and/or don't have any knowledge about the subject ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like IE8 and lower versions don't get to know what `type` of content fancybox should open from the dynamically added link. Why? don't ask me, it's IE.

As a workaround, you can set the `type` of content (`inline` in this scenario) inside the dynamically added link using the (HTML5) `data-fancybox-type` attribute like :

```
<a id="fbLink" data-fancybox-type="inline" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fbox">see fancybox</a>
```

Your full script may look now like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //loading the opening link to a div with jquery
        // added data-fancybox-type to the link
        $('#linkdiv').html('<a id="fbLink" data-fancybox-type="inline" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fbox">see fancybox</a>');
        //opening the fancybox
        $('#fbLink').fancybox({
            'afterLoad': function () {
                $('#fancyboxdiv').html('<h1>Fancybox</h1>');
            },
                'afterClose': function () {
                $('#fancyboxdiv').empty();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

That should do the trick (tested it with IE7)